# ANTLR Recursive replace

Tags: recursion, url-rewriting, antlr

I want to change DBMS_LOB.substr  using antlr:
Example1:
Input:

```
DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(field_name1, 4000, 1)
```

Output:

```
SUBSTR(field_name1, 1, 4000)
```

We need to do 2 things:
1) remove DBMS_LOB.
2) interchange 2nd & 3rd arguments

I'm able to override the rule for the specific token and change it to handle the above.

Problem to handle recursive:
I have an input something like this:

```
DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(field_name1, DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(field_name2, 6000, 1), DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(field_name3, 8000, 1))
```

I want to change something like:

```
SUBSTR(field_name1, SUBSTR(field_name3, 1, 8000), SUBSTR(field_name2, 1, 6000))
```

How to handle when the DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR appears multiple levels within the original statement.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to tell without knowing the approach you use to implement this task.

But in general, the advice may look like this:

**Think of the inner DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR statements as single nonterminal statements**.

What I mean is that there should be no difference in your replacing algorithm when dealing with either

"DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(field_name1, 4000, 1)"

or

"DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(field_name1, DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(field_name2, 6000, 1), DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(field_name3, 8000, 1))".

In both cases **4000** and **DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(field_name2, 6000, 1)** are just **arguments**, no matter what they look like or consist of.

Comment: We use listener to modify the contents. When we walk through the tree.                                            We have a method something like entersubstr which will we replace the 2nd and 3rd field.  Ex: DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(field_name3, 8000, 1)  will be changed to DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(field_name3, 1, 8000) It works fine.                                         Ex2: DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(field_name1, DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(field_name2, 6000, 1), DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(field_name3, 8000, 1)) We there are multiple substr functions present, when we try to apply the same method to modify we get: OUTOFBOUNDARY exception

Comment: Can you provide your code and the stacktrace of the exception?